# Tex file is no longer generating pdf

Tags: errors, compiling

I am creating an article on tex works. I managed to generate a title page, contents and first section, everything compiled fine. I added a subsection and now the pdf will not update. It does not require any extra files. I have tried to create a new file of the same content (with and without the most recent code added) with no success. I have tried a different directory. Now not even a simple Hello world file will create and with this, I am generating this error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./3.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 21 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file 3.aux.

! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{docuemnt}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \end{docuemnt}

?
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have `\end{docuemnt}` where `\end{document}` is intended.

Comment: Thanks! That was a typo out of frustration, I guess. Do you know why I am unable to generate a pdf or things to look for?

Comment: Fix the typo in your .tex document. It will then work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Correct the typo. If it still will not compile, post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for people to take a look at.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is caused by a typo.